# Загрузка фотографии на сервер

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Загружаю фотку на сервер вк:

```
    $post_params = array(
        'file1' => '@'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_POST['img']
    );
    $ch = curl_init($resp->response->upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    $resp = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```

Результат:

```
{"server":628129,"photo":"[]","hash":"bf78bf3aea9664077e28e6746d4d3818"}
```

Я пробовал и file_exist-ом проверять существование файла, пробовал realpath делать, прописывать жестко путь до файла. Менял опции cURL, брал примеры из сети.

Многие пишут, что photos пустое т.к. в реале я не передаю файл фотографии.

Может ли это оказаться не так? Может ли быть проблема в чем то-еще? Например, в получении адреса загрузки, хотя тут все по доке

```
$url_upload_img = https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?user_id=
  '.$user_id.'&access_token='.$access_token
```

Comment: `filename` наряду с `file1`, кажется, ещё добавлять нужно (не путь с именем, а просто имя файла).

Comment: По факту оно выглядит так @/home/admin/web/my-site.ru/public_html/post-img/2016-02-11/4a2436874448a547304b7fb26a54f3ee.jpg

Comment: Значит в `$post_params` добавьте `filename => "4a2436874448a547304b‌​7fb26a54f3ee.jpg"`

Comment: Не работает... Да и в доке про это ни чего не сказано, там вообще только сказано что названия должны идти file1,file2 и т.д.

Comment: Да, именно так. Но я пока это поле не добавил, у меня также массив `photo` возвращался пустым и загрузка картинок в итоге не работала.

Comment: Мне не помогло((

Comment: А Вы именно добавили этот `filename` или заменили им `file1`? Правильно - первое.

Comment: $post_params = array(
       'file1' => '@/home/admin/web/my-site.ru/public_html/post-img/2016-02-11/4a2436874448a547304b7fb26a54f3ee.jpg',
       'filename' => '4a2436874448a547304b‌​7fb26a54f3ee.jpg'
   );

Comment: Я в curl не разбираюсь, но точно ли отправляется в формате `multipart/form-data`? Ну и поле надо назвать не `file1`, а `photo`, как в ответе упомянули

Comment: Добавил заголовок руками, тоже самое пока что. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;'
      ));

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В итоге, разобрался.

```
$img_real_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/..".$_POST['img']);
$curl_file = curl_file_create($img_real_path,'image/jpeg','test_name.jpg');
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => $upload_url,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("photo" => $curl_file)
));
$img_attach = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по приведённому ответу сервера ВК, где присутствует пустое поле `photo`, а не 'photos_list', вы загружаете фото **на стену пользователя** (или аватарку).

В этих случаях поле с файлом картинки должно называться не `file1`, а `photo` ([документация](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)).

Comment: Запрос - ответ:array(1) {
  ["photo"]=>
  string(99) "@/home/admin/web/mysite.ru/public_html/post-img/2016-02-11/4a2436874448a547304b7fb26a54f3ee.jpg"
}
string(72) "{"server":628129,"photo":"[]","hash":"bf78bf3aea9664077e28e6746d4d3818"}"

Comment: Проверьте перед отправкой, что файл доступен скрипту: `if( !is_readable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_POST['img'])) exit(100);`

Comment: Так и делал перед отправкой

Comment: Можете ссылку дать на тот раздел доки, который говорит что нужно photo называть, я такого не видел, может я целый рздел пропустил...

Comment: В ответе есть ссылка

Answer (score 0):

У меня возникла проблема с тем, что при загрузке изображений уже по запрошенному `upload_url` получал следующее:

```
{"server":628129,"photo":"[]","hash":"bf78bf3aea9664077e28e6746d4d3818"}
```

то есть пустой "photo".
Решение оказалось следующим: VK не принимал файлы с кириллицей, поэтому пришлось перед каждой отправкой менять имя файла.Очень помогла следующая [инструкция](https://toster.ru/q/235833)