# Загрузка изображения через VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Задача — залить через Vkontakte API изображение в альбом себе. Воспользовавшись рабочим примером https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/492049/176892 попытался воспроизвести и у себя:

```
<?
    $img_real_path = '/home/***/docs/wp-content/uploads/gigapixel/preview.jpg';
    //$img_real_path = '/home/***/docs/wp-content/themes/videodessa/shareimg.php';

    $curl_file = curl_file_create($img_real_path,'image/jpg','test_name.jpg');

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $_POST['upload_url'],
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("photo" => $curl_file),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8')
    ));
    echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Все работает, файл заливается. Но есть нюанс. Работает это только с живым jpg. Если попытаться скормить картинку, которая генерится через php

```
$img_real_path = '/home/***/docs/wp-content/themes/videodessa/shareimg.php';
```

все плохо:

```
{"server":624829,"photo":"[]","hash":"09b3a913eea42395dfba724db3adef29f","__error":"[!files_saveAlbumPhotoStorageEngine(file:test_name.jpg, res:-1, descr:)]"}
```

На всякий случай прикладываю скрипт генерации картинки `shareimg.php`:

```
<?
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");

    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $y = $_GET['y'];
    $size = 200;

    $fullImage = getimagesize("../../uploads/gigapixel/full.jpg");

    $origImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("../../uploads/gigapixel/orig.jpg");
    $origW = imagesx($origImage);
    $origH = imagesy($origImage);

    $deltaW = $origW / $fullImage[0];
    $deltaH = $origH / $fullImage[1];

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);

    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $origImage, 0, 0, $x*$deltaW-$size/2, $y*$deltaH-$size/2, $size, $size, $size, $size);

    return imagejpeg($newImage);

?>
```

Но есть мнение, что это просто `curl` надо хорошему научить. А в нем я совсем не силен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению вы не можете в CURL'ом передать генерируемое изображение, но вы же всегда можете сохранить сгенерированное изображение во временную папку и передать его.